# How to install new fonts on the Amazon Kindle Paperwhite eInk eBook reader?

Tags: kindle

The Kindle Paperwhite reader comes with a few fonts pre-installed. However, I would like to install more fonts on the device. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the root folder of the Kindle, create a file named `USE_ALT_FONTS`.
2. Also, create a folder named `fonts`.
3. Copy the desired `.otf` or `.ttf` font files into the newly created `fonts` folder.
4. Restart the Kindle for the changes to take effect.